# How to iterate over a Triple in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have list of three set of values which are related to each other. i.e. Roll Number, Student Name and School Name.

I am using Kotlin [Triple](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/) to store them.
Below is the code:

```
val studentData = listOf(
    Triple(first = "1", second ="Sam", third = "MIT"),
    Triple(first = "2", second ="Johnny", third = "SYM"),
    Triple(first = "3", second ="Depp", third = "PIT")
)
```

And now I need to build a function which will accept roll number and will return either student name or school name. Something like below:

```
fun getStudentDetails(rollNumber: String) : String {
    //...
    //return student name or school name 
}
```

How to achieve this?
How to traverse the `Triple` in most preformat way considering below:
a) the time and space complexity
b) the list of student details can grow large

Comment: Any reason why you'd use a Triple here? why not use a data class and/or a hashmap instead of a list? It would decrease lookups, which appears to be what you're mostly concerned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `rollNumber` is a `String` you can just filter the list using `firstOrNull` and return the student name or school name:

```
fun getStudentDetails(rollNumber: String) : String =
    studentData.firstOrNull({ (roll, _, _) -> 
        roll == rollNumber 
    })?.second ?: "No student with $rollNumber"
```

The space complexity would be constant, the time complexity is O(n) at the worst case.